# Can we have a Time clocked transaction in Tezos?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I want to make an escrow contract where the transaction can be done after an interval. Is it possible / any hack that can make it happen?

The balance should get deducted from the sender beforehand and the recipient will only get the amount after a specific time period.

Answer (score 4):

You have access to a "time" with `sp.now` so you can compute conditions, etc.

There is nothing like "send in 30 minutes". You need external input to trigger operations Tezos.

You can compute with timestamps and forbid some actions for a period.

Deducting the balance to the sender means sending the amount to the contract.

Recipient will *not* get the amount after a specific time period, however, he will be able to call an entry point to get this amount *after* a specific time period (if you program it in SmartPy).